# Why do I get "syntax error near unexpected token `(' "?

Tags: bash, unix

I want to go through many directories and remove all the files except some that meet certain criterion. I have the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in */
do
  cd $i
  rm !(*M.*)
  cd ..
done
```

However, when I run the script I get the following error:

```
script1.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `('
script1.sh: line 5: `    rm !(*M.*)'
```

What could be wrong? I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you expect `!()` to specify? Note that `(` in the shell usually starts a sub-shell.

Comment: rm doesn't have "except" support... you specify something on the command line, rm is going to try and remove it.

Comment: Do you mean to set `extglob` maybe?

Comment: Btw. Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: I can do "rm !(*M.*)" from the command line, but not from a *.sh file.. I know parentheses won't work.. are there any alternatives? I want to remove all files except those ones that contain "M." in its filename..

Comment: @DanielUrencio That's because your *login shell* reads some profile that sets `shopt extglob`, while a shell executing a script does not.

Comment: You are all right, thank you so much! Problem solved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should enable *extglob* to use invert or negative wildcards:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Note that you can keep this on all the time, it is not harmful.

That said, you are not forced to use a loop in your code and can directly put in your script:

```
rm */!(*M.*)
```

You can visit this post for other solutions:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78376/in-linux-how-to-delete-all-files-except-the-pattern-txt

Comment: Thank you very much! That did it for me.. Just one last question.. Could you recommend any source (book, website...) where I can learn more about this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob would be a first step and practice is the next one. Good luck !

Comment: @Philou: That was classic :). Worth noting that if the OP wishes to delete files recursively he could use `rm -R */!(*M.*)`